# Wooden posts for backyard pullup bar

Tags: wood, post

I want to install a backyard pullup bar similar to [this one](http://www.fitnesshq.com/making-a-diy-pull-up-bar/). It's essentially 2 pressure treated wooden posts connected with a metal bar and anchored into the ground with concrete.

I'm about 180lbs and primarily do weighted pullups. Sometimes I use over 100lbs of extra weight so it should be able to handle  about 300lbs comfortably. **Would 4x6 posts be sufficient or would it be wiser to use 6x6 posts?** The 6x6s seem to be a lot more costly so I'd prefer to go with the 4x6s if they're a reasonable choice for me.

Anything else I should keep in mind? The author dug the holes 2ft deep but I'm planning to make them 3ft deep as that seems like it would add more stability.

Location is in Western Washington state, near Seattle. According to [this article](https://www.hammerpedia.com/washington-frost-line/) the frost depth is about 10" unless I'm misunderstanding.

Thanks

Comment: The metal bar and how it attaches is the main concern.  You also need to know the frost depth for your local area to determine the depth of the hole(if more than one year of use).  4x6 will handle the weight just fine.

Comment: 2ft or 3ft fine - depends on the side loads you intend to inflict. Are you going to take a run up and swing?

Comment: @crip659, I was actually going to buy one of the X-431 crossmembers from here: https://www.roguefitness.com/monster-lite-crossmembers and just use that. There's no good pics but it has two big holes per side and I was just going to drive a long lag bolt into each hole.

Comment: @SolarMike no running up to it but I guess I will occasionally do more explosive movements like muscle ups.

Comment: Even 4x4s are great plenty.

Answer (score 4):

4x6 will be fine. I didn't bother to look up the tables, but a 4x6s vertical load capacity in this situation will be well over 10,000 lbs each.

Make sure to orient them such that the wide face side holds the bar.

I agree you should put them deeper in the ground, your main issues will be bending moments. Swinging front to back won't bother the 4x6 at all, but you could cause the footings to wiggle loose in the ground. I would put them as deep as you can tolerate, around 4 feet or more . If you live where it freezes, you'll want to exceed the frost depth as well. I would also double the amount of concrete. 160 lbs of concrete for each footing I think is a little light, even for kids.

Comment: I agree, but 4' seems excessive. If the soil is that soft, go 3' and add a 4x6 cross member a few inches below grade and about 2' past the posts.